# dc motor positive (RED) and negative (BLACK) terminology/notation

Tags: motor, dc-motor, power-electronics, wiring

**Is there a standard wiring notation of a permanent magnet dc motor terminology ?**

in other-words if **12v** is applied to the **red terminal** and **ground** to the **black terminal** does this cause **rotation in CW** in ***ALL*** motors for example and vis-versa ??

i have tested 10 different motors so far with success , but i don't know if this is just by chance !

Comment: It's standard, but other wire standards are also used with stripes in automotive

Comment: Are you talking industrial motors, hobby motors, toy motors, or what?

Comment: @Transistor industrial offcourse . but from different manufacturers , china ,india , uk , france ,usa etc....

Comment: @TonyStewart , can you reference it might contain other helpful info .

Comment: Sometimes "standard colours" like car battery terminals and jumper cables have unknown origins, which is now academic after a lifetime of common use.  For those colour blind, other markings are available.  Every company, industry may choose specific may choose to adopt familiarity or custom standards.